# Loading and Unloading the .arx file with LISP

Tags: visual-c++, lisp, autocad, autodesk, autolisp

I have few .arx applications for AutoCAD. In these applications few are menu based and others are command line. Now what I am trying to do is,

1. Load the .arx app,
2. run it and then
3. unload it once the .arx application runs through a LISP command.
   .arx applications run once the user clicks on the tabs that are provided. 
   .arx applications are written in VC++.

Now I have a lisp file, which gets loaded once the user starts AutoCAD. In the lisp files I have declared these functions for various .arx applications;

(defun c:XYZ_program() (command) (command) (arxload "C:/ABC/XYZ.arx") (command "XYZ_program") (arxunload "XYZ.arx") )

It works fine for Programs which need input data from Menu based forms, but says error unloading xyz.arx for programs which need command line input.

I was wondering if there were any commands in LISP that will make sure arxunload "XYZ.arx" will execute only once (command "XYZ_program") is executed.

I am not sure on how to approach this problem. Any help with the same would be greatly appreciated.

> Code I am currently using is this
>   ;

```
(
  defun c:XYZ_program() (command) (command)
   (arxload "C:/Example/Folder/XYZ.arx") 
   (command "XYZ_program") 
   ads_queueexpr( (arxunload "XYZ.arx") ) 
)
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Visual-C++

Comment: @DavidChing ObjectArx applications are written in VC++. So I think there is a way where we can achieve the goal of unloading the .arx app. Developers who work with VC++ and ObjectARX wuld have a better idea about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from your question, but it sounds like the module cannot be unloaded because it is actively executing a command that is waiting for user input. So, I think you are asking how to postpone the unloading until the command is finished executing. The answer to that question is to use ads_queueexpr() to queue the (arxunload "XXX") function from within the command itself.

However, you are creating much bigger problems for yourself by attempting to unload the module. Unloading takes time, so it most certainly does not help performance. The correct solution to your problem is to not unload your modules and leave the unloading to AutoCAD.

Comment: Appreciate your response Owen, With respect to performance, I did read in the Object Arx documentation, that unloading the .arx application does help in performance as they get stored in memory. We currently have around 25 .arx application loaded together, so hence was moving in that direction. Also when we try to update the users, the user has to close the application (AutoCAD) as the arx's are loaded. So was just curious if unloading would help us in both the scenarios.

Comment: I have pasted the LISP command I am using currently with ads_queueexpr() in the question, but it still does not work. I am wondering if I am using it correctly? Thanks

Comment: The documentation is wrong. Unloading will hurt performance and will not help with memory. Loaded modules do not get stored in memory unless the memory is free or the code is running. The fact that unloading would reduce the total time a module is not updatable still does not guarantee that hot updates are possible at any given time, so I think that is a very limited benefit. There are more reliable solutions for pushing updates.

Comment: Thanks Owen, I will definitely consider your points, also I would appreciate if you could just take a look at the code that I have written using ads_queueexpr(). It still does not work, am I implementing it in a correct way? -------------------------(
  defun c:XYZ_program() (command) (command)
   (arxload "C:/Example/Folder/XYZ.arx") 
   (command "XYZ_program") 
   ads_queueexpr( (arxunload "XYZ.arx") ) 
)

Comment: ads_queueexpr() is a C function. It belongs in your implementation of the XYZ_program command, not in the lisp code that calls the command.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for that. Is there any function that can be used in LISP to add it to the queue or to have a dependency to wait until the previous command executes completely? I am totally new to LISP and have never used it before. I managed to write the above function, and am struggling with the current problem.

Comment: Currently I am using --> ads_queueexpr(_T(" (unload \"Remove_Letter.arx\") ") ); in my VC++ program at the end of the VC++ program, but when I run it in AutoCAD, it executes the program and while unloading says, Unknown command "ARX") ". I would appreciate some help with this.

Comment: Thanks Owen. The solution given by you worked. Appreciate a lot.

Comment: I didn't even think about that. I've used queueexpr a few times  in c#. Glad you guys got it figured out.

Comment: @owen you should post your answer as an answer so others can see the correct answer and you can get the points, buddy.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2013/ENU/index.html?url=files/GUID-3FF72BD0-9863-4739-8A45-B14AF1B67B06.htm,topicNumber=d30e502824

```
(defun c:Load()
    (arxload "the\\file\\path")
    ; run the app
)
```

Try this:

```
(arxload "C:/ABC/XYZ.arx" nil) 

(defun c:XYZ_program() 
    (command) 
    (command)
    (command "XYZ_program")
    (arxunload "XYZ.arx" nil) 
);
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot Trae, for the link, Appreciate it. I kind of know the commands, for loading and unloading, but my issue is something else. I am using the following command, (defun c:XYZ_program() (command) (command) (arxload "C:/ABC/XYZ.arx") (command "XYZ_program") (arxunload "XYZ.arx") )
 but whenever the program XYZ needs inputs from command line, the arxunload("XYZ.arx") runs before it and displays an error message, and then the XYZ program runs fine. What I want is the XYZ.arx to execute first and then unload("XYZ.arx") should run.

Comment: Why do you need to unload it?

Comment: I can't remember exactly which one, but when you close the drawing or application it will dispose automatically.

Comment: I want to dynamically load the programs when the user seletc the programs and then unload it once its done.

Comment: It just may be me but I don't see the need to unload it when it will take care of that for you OnClose.

Comment: I did read in the ObjectArx Documentation. Dynamically loading .arx and unloading them thus help in better performance, specailly when the arx's are heavy. So I was looking forward for it. I can load them dynamically, but unloading is a issue only for arx. which need command line input. For menu driven input, it works fine as intented.

Comment: Could it be the VC++ command line program has a command prompt window that doesn't close, thus the unload error?  If you build the VC++ program, by specifying the [linker option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc1zstk(v=vs.100).aspx) `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS`

Comment: It did not work Trae. Thanks for all the help though. Appreciate it.

Comment: @DavidChing I am little confused when you mention, the command prompt window? Currently the VC++ program uses the AutoCAD's command line input.

Comment: I'm not familiar with AutoCad or these arx programs.  But you said the VC++ programs which used the menu unloaded fine, but not the ones that received input from the command line.  If you create a VC++ console app (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE), when you run it from Explorer, it runs in a black command prompt window.  This is different from a GUI app with a menu (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS) that does does not run in a black command prompt window.  So I was suggesting you build the console program as a GUI program (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS) as it might then unload just like the others.

Comment: @DavidChing Currently I am using (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS) for all the programs. Do you think anything else that we should consider?

Comment: If you start the programs from Explorer instead of AutoCad, do they function properly?

Comment: @TraeMoore Trae, if you don.t mind and if you found this question important, can you please upvote it. My reputation is only 10 right now, so I cannot edit any answers. I would really appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: @TraeMoore I did get the answer. Owen above suggested the correct path for getting the solution. Thanks for all your help.